# Node.js + Mocha + Should.js How to test an error being thrown by an eventemitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I want to test the case where an error is thrown in my search.coffee class:

Let's assume that for my test, I cn fo

search.coffee

```
{ EventEmitter } = require 'events'
connectors       = require './connectors'

class Search extends EventEmitter
  constructor: (@query, @credentials, dispatch = true) ->
    @connectors = @_connectors()

    if @connectors.length == 0
      # want to test this
      @emit 'error', new Error 'Search could not be dispatched to any connectors'

    @_dispatch(query, connector) for connector in @connectors if dispatch
```

I have tried the following, however since an event is being emitted with the error, the return of the `new Search()` itself does not throw an error.  How can I catch this thrown error?

search_spec.coffee

```
Search = require '../../src/search'

describe "search.coffee", ->

  describe "constructor", ->
    it 'should return an error if no credentials match loaded connectors', ->
      new Search("foo", { }, false).should.throw()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, nothing is *thrown* here. The [default behavior](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) if no event listener is installed is for Node to print a stack trace and exit. It looks like a thrown exception but you can't catch it. Systems like `should.throw`, `assert.Throw`, etc. rely on being able to catch the exception. Not possible here.

Now, there's a problem. You are emitting the `'error'` event in your constructor. Who has the opportunity to call the `on` method to install a listener so that when this `emit` happens, *someone* will receive it? The object is not constructed yet. The object could call `on` on itself but no one outside can.

Options:

1. Don't `emit` an error, but instead `throw` an error. For the reason given above, this is the option I'd prefer if this were my code.
2. Add an additional parameter to the constructor. This would be a listener that `Search` installs on itself right away to listen for error events. So in testing, a listener could be passed to the constructor and then you just test that it is called.
3. If it does not make sense to allow callers to install a listener like mentioned in the 1st option, `Search` could install its own listener, which could record that that the object is dead (for instance, `this.dead = true`). Then test for this flag.
4. Or if the current design and behavior is the desired one (the constructor emits `'error'`, which causes Node.js to exit), modify the previous option. Devise a way to indicate to `Search` that it is running in a test environment. When it detects that it is in testing, it adds a listener like in the previous option.

Comment: Interesting -- so in another class of mine (Client.coffee) that is not in my original question, binds to the `.on('error')` event.  But as I understand it, no matter what, since I will never have the chance to first instantiate a `Search` and then bind to the `error` event, my `Client` class will never be able to receive this error event?

Comment: That's right. You'd have to use one of the options I listed in my answer to work around it. Another option I've not mentioned but which occurs to me now would be to use another object as a communication channel. This object would be created before ``Search`` and passed to ``Search``'s constructor. A ``Search`` object would emit events on this communication channel.

Comment: I actually discovered that `@emit 'error', new Error 'Search could not be dispatched to any connectors'` will throw an error which can be caught if the unit test is structured as an anonymous function, like so: `(-> new Search("foo", { })).should.throw('Search could not be dispatched to any connectors')`